# preg_replace URLs but not images

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$title =  $_POST['title'];

$post = stripslashes($_POST['TextArea']);

$link = preg_replace('"(http://www\S+)"','<a href="$1">$1</a>', $post);

echo $link;
```

After submit my form the above script replace all links inside textarea
and the result for images is to be broken.

Is there a way to replace links but not images?

While url works perfect the result for images in browser is

```
<img src="<a href="http://...myimage.jpg"">http://.../myimage.jpg"</a> height="150" width="150">
```

[image]
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can we see an example of the input text and your expected output text?

Comment: DOMDocument would has zero effect on this Joseph. He's simply trying to convert non-HTML links to HTML links.

Comment: use a negative assertion to exclude `src="` before any http-type text, which would exclude `<img` tags.

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_replace('"(?<!src=[\"\'])(http://www\S+)"','<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text)
```

This will only convert `http://www` links that are not preceded by `src="` or `src='`.

Comment: @user2026955 don't forget to upvote/accept answers that help you.  Also be aware that `src=` without a `"` or `'` will not work properly

Comment: Sure , thank you again ! I 'll mention your help when I will publish the final script , Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(?<!src=[\"\'])(http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[\/a-zA-Z0-9%\?\.\-]*)(?=$|<|\s)/','<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

This is the correct way because previous solution does not finish url when necessary